# No more ssh access after setting read only access to a user on my linux server

Tags: ssh, permissions, setfacl

I just added a user on my linux server and tried to set read only access to this new one. In the process, I wrongly entered a command to set user's rx access on `/`

```
setfacl -R -m u:user:rx /
```

and now, I have no more ssh root access to my server (connection closed error).

Could you please help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it by removing the ACL masks:

```
setfacl -R -b /
```